# javascript function attached to window object not executing because it is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm having a problem when executing the function that I've attached to the window object:

**someLibrary.js**

```
(function($,window){
   var bar = function(config){
      var init = function(){/*...*/};
      return { init:init };
   };
   window.bar = bar;
})(jQuery, window);
```

**somePage.html**

```
<script src="someLibrary.js" ></script>
<...>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var baz = new bar(); //bar is not defined
</script>
```

I cannot use `bar` because it's not yet defined, 
Do I have to wrap my call to `bar` within a `$(window).load`? 
Is something wrong with what I'm trying to do?

**UPDATE**: All of this code is executed within a colorbox (not iframe), jQuery is already loaded and the `$(window).load` already happened :(

**parentPage.html**

```
<head>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="colorbox.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
   <a href="somepage.html" id="link"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#link').colorbox();
   </script>
</html>
```

I also noticed that it only happens when `someLibrary.js` is called from a different domain :S

Thanks

Comment: you don't define until $.ready(), but you invoke immediately in your 2nd script. i don't know why you tell you first one to wait until ready(), there's no dom code in there at all...

Comment: nah, the posted js is fine.

Comment: @dandavis Where do you see a ready handler? There is no none, and no function being passed to `$()` either. OP is using an IIFE.

Comment: The presented code is perfectly valid http://jsfiddle.net/2ZuLZ/ you will have to elaborate how to it is executed within a colorbox w/o iframe. Is it loaded through Ajax?

Comment: The code won't work as is. `var init = function(){...};` -- you need to elaborate on the `...`. If you remove `jquery` and the `...` then your code works.

Comment: Sorry @NagaJolokia, those periods were to represent more code, I already commented them.

Comment: Try using jsfiddle to make a working example.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thanks for your help, it seems that the problem is the domain where the js is loaded from. (no crossdomain error is shown, the file is loaded but in a different manner)

Answer (score 0):

The scripts on your page will execute in order, so the somelib file will load before your code that calls it.

The other potential reason for it being undefined is if you didn't include the jQuery script earlier in your page.

```
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script src="someLibrary.js" ></script>
<...>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var baz = new bar(); //bar is not defined
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question, I'm using colorbox(not iframe) and jQuery is already loaded, I put someLibrary.js in the header and calling "bar" at the bottom of the page